# How come my DotNet Blazor WASM app fails to finish loading when I try to read some data from a local SQL database from WebAppBuilder in "program.cs'?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linux, blazor

I am fairly newbie to dotnet...

I am just testing out connecting to a local sql db, and the connection is successful, and data is read. But then my actual app in the browser becomes stuck on loading, and there are no errors or exceptions thrown.

Here is my complete Program.cs file; the commented out block is what causes the app to fail loading.

To be clear: if I try accessing the sql db with the commented out code, I recieve the requested data from the db in the console successfully... but the app in browser is then stuck on loading with no errors.

```
global using BlazorShop.Shared;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder( args );

/*try {
    var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder { ConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString( "DefaultConnection" ) };
    using var connection = new SqlConnection( sqlBuilder.ConnectionString );

    Console.WriteLine( "\nQuery data example:" );
    Console.WriteLine( "=========================================\n" );

    const string sql = "SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases";

    using var command = new SqlCommand( sql, connection );
    connection.Open();
    using SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while ( reader.Read() ) {
        Console.WriteLine( "{0} {1}", reader.GetString( 0 ), reader.GetString( 1 ) );
    }

    reader.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
catch ( SqlException e ) {
    Console.WriteLine( e.ToString() + "vregfqrevcqersgvcrqedsvcqedsvcerdsverqvrqesgvreqsdbvrqe" );
}
Console.ReadLine();*/

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if ( app.Environment.IsDevelopment() ) {
    //app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else {
    app.UseExceptionHandler( "/Error" );
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Sorry ahead of time for this stupid question... Have you tried removing the Console.ReadLine(); call? I'm sure you have, but It is all I can see atm. Also, maybe try add a full Exception catch, not just one for SqlException. I know it runs but that is all I've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine()` was causing an issue in my IDE. Problem solved.